# How to test if $n!+1$ is prime or not?

Tags: prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

For $n=0,1,2,3,11,27,37,41,73,77,116,154,320,340,399,427,872,1477,6380,26951,...,$
$n!+1$ is prime. But how can you prove that this is always the case? Especially for the larger ones.

For example $1477!+1$ this number has several hundert digits, I know we can apply stochastic factor or prime algorithms, but how can you do the final proof without testing all factors?

Comment: $n!+1$ isn't prime always. So what are you trying to prove? Or are you asking for some way to check whether for a particular $n$, $n!+1$ is prime?

Comment: So basically you're asking how people test for primality. Well, if you want to be sure, you need to use a deterministic primality test. Checking all the factors is such a test, but it is very slow. You can read here for more information on some other tests, but they can be very difficult. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: Let $m=n!+1.$ Since you have the complete prime factorization of $m-1$ you can use Theorem 1 (improved Lucas test) from http://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove3_1.html to computionally test the primality.

Comment: Actually both, how can you prove $n!+1$ is prime or how can you prove $n!+1$ isn't prime, without stochastic tests such as PollardRho etc.